# Moving Outlook message with specific subject to Subfolders

Tags: vba, outlook, subdirectory, inbox

I am trying to write a brief VBA script that will move incoming messages from my Outlook Inbox to a subfolder.  This is what I currently have (assembled from various posts), but I'm not getting any result when I send test emails.  If there are any other posts that would relate to this, I would appreciate it!

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  ' Default local Inbox
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Set myInbox = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item

    If Msg.SenderEmailAddress = "name@example.com" Then
        If InStr(0, Msg.Subject, "Subject Title", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Msg.Move myInbox.Folders("Test").Subfolder("Destination")
        End If
    End If

  End If
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't define and initialize the Items object properly. For example:

```
 Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

 Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
     Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items  
 End Sub 

 Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)  
    ' do something here
 End Sub
```

Be aware, the ItemAdd event is not fired when more than 16 items is added at the same time. This is a known issue in the OOM.

Try to use the NewMailEx event of the Application class instead. And I'd suggest reading the following series of articles:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

Finally, is your macro enabled in Outlook? Have you checked out the Trust center settings?

Comment: Well, I also updated the post. See the changes above.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!  My macros are enabled, and I will experiment with the NewMailEx application.  For the time being however, I'm still not getting any response from the current macro - I don't even get a notification when the test email comes through (i.e. no errors).  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check out the Trust center settings in Outlook? Is your macro allowed to run?

Comment: I changed the Macro Settings within the Trust Center to "Enable all macros".  I believe this is the only relevant setting to running macros, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in ThisOutlookSession.

Just above your code put

```
Public WithEvents Items As Items
```

When using the built-in class module ThisOutlookSession, Sub Application_Startup() initializes the handler.