# VBA Outlook Rule call subroutine to save to disk

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments, outlook-2016

I completely lost my VBA touch, anyone that can help, I greatly appreciate it.
For outlook desktop I want to a rule that automatically moves item to a folder, marks it as read and calls a script. ( I managed to do that )

How to enable script in outlook 2016: https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/
For the subroutine to be seen by Rule Wizard, the argument must by type MailItem.

The script I want to run, is to save the message identified by the rule to disk as a txt file, and for that I am using:

In the module "ThisOutlookSession" the following code ( found it on [Outlook VBA macro for saving emails copies in a local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039209/outlook-vba-macro-for-saving-emails-copies-in-a-local-folder) ) :

```
Public Sub SaveToDiskScript(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Const olMsg As Long = 0 '0=Text format (.txt) -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olsaveastype

    Dim m As MailItem
    Dim savePath As String


    Set m = Item

    savePath = "C:\Users\im.a.pretty.user\Desktop\StorageFolder\"
    savePath = savePath & m.Subject & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd-hhNNss")
    savePath = savePath & ".txt"


    m.SaveAs savePath, olMsg


End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: @niton how to make it work, because at the moment it doesnt

Comment: [What Do You Mean "It Doesn't Work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work) 1) It does nothing. 2) It moves the item but does not save. 3) There is a file permission error. Consider describing the rule.

Comment: @niton version 1 - it does nothing

Comment: macro security is set to enable all macros :(

Comment: Set a breakpoint to verify the rule calls the code.  To test further https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029141/debugging-an-outlook-2007-script-fired-by-a-rule/58049467#58049467

Comment: There is likely a mistake in the rule. Regardless a rule with a move may lose the reference to the item and not save the attachment. One alternative is [ItemAdd on the inbox with the move in the code, after the save.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052041/moving-outlook-message-with-specific-subject-to-subfolders) A second alternative is ItemAdd on the subfolder with the move in the rule.

Answer (score 0):

The file path passed to the `SaveAs` method of the `MailItem` class is built based on the `Subject` line which may contain forbidden symbols:

```
savePath = "C:\Users\im.a.pretty.user\Desktop\StorageFolder\"
savePath = savePath & m.Subject & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd-hhNNss")
savePath = savePath & ".txt"
```

I'd recommend checking whether it contains any forbidden symbols before, see [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names) for more information.

Also you may try to specify a different folder without dots in the file path.

Comment: hi, thank you for the suggestion, I have removed the m.Subject part and changed location to "C:\folder\" but it still doesnt work

Comment: What path did you specify exactly?

Comment: savePath="C:\folder\"

Comment: The system drive requires admin privileges, try choosing another disk.

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint and run your macro to see what errors could be thrown. For example, you may get the currently selected item in Outlook and pass it to the method. The Selection property of the Explorer class can be used for that.